# Is there a way to make cargo build always include the target's name in the output directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

By default, `cargo build` will put its output in `target/debug/`, and `cargo build --target foo` will put it in `target/foo/debug/` *even if it is the same target!*

Is there a way to make `cargo build` always put its output in `target/<default_target>/debug` without having to specify `--target`?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean... but wouldn't placing `[build]
target = "yourtarget"` in `.cargo/config` do the trick?

Comment: Wouldn't that always mean it uses `yourtarget`? That isn't what I want. I want it to use its default target but to put it in a directory with the name of that target.